# Firestore & Spring Boot

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to CRUD operations on Firestore database from spring boot server, but I can't find anywhere how to:
1. Connect my spring boot server to Firestore
2. CRUD ops on my Firestore database

Can anyone help me out to connect my server to Firestore database?

Thanks

Comment: The closest i found was a java based example for firestore, please try: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/server/samples-java

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is initialize firebase app:

```
    InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY);
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

and then you can run firestore database

```
    Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

    ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> query = db.collection(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME).get();
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = query.get();
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.getDocuments();
```

I think that it will be helpfull https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides

Comment: the op asked for firestore but you have posted code for Firbase?

Answer (score 1):

As per Spring Cloud GCP Documentation there is a starter library
see [Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.0.M1/#_cloud_firestore)

Also this is an example how to implement it [sample project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore-sample)